# Markers, how to insert an image in the balloon

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

In api v1 I used overlays when I want to add a marker in the map and I used the [mapviewballoons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) class, where I can add any image in the ballon. Now in v2 I use Markers and I dont know how to insert an image in the balloon. I search in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/package-summary) but I didnt found anything. There is any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "balloon", you mean the [info window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows) that appears when you tap the marker, you need to implement an `InfoWindowAdapter` to return the contents of that "balloon" and attach it to your `GoogleMap` via `setInfoWindowAdapter()`. Your `InfoWindowAdapter` can implement `getWindowContents()` in such a way that includes your image. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Popups) demonstrates this technique.